# Get info about git word-diff merging lines

Tags: git, git-diff, word-diff

I am trying to build by-line history of file and I got strange behavour in `git diff`/`git log`... commands when using `--word-diff` mode. It sometimes merges some lines.

For example, if old version of file was:

```
r = ioctl(hdev->control, VHOST_SET_LOG_BASE,
    (uint64_t)(unsigned long)hdev->log);
```

its being converted to:

```
r = hdev->vhost_ops->vhost_call(hdev, VHOST_SET_LOG_BASE, hdev->log);
```

(These lines are from [this](https://github.com/OSLL/qemu-xtensa) project distributed with GPL license)

Simple `git diff` gives me normal output (2 lines deleted, one added), but `git diff --word-diff` gives me this:

```
r = [-ioctl(hdev->control,-]{+hdev->vhost_ops->vhost_call(hdev,+}
    VHOST_SET_LOG_BASE, [-(uint64_t)(unsigned long)hdev->log);-]{hdev->log);}
```

Same output will be emitted in `--word-diff=porcelain` mode, it's not text-mode bug.

As I'm trying to get by-line history of file, my methods are failing on this piece of `git log`. I see that `git` is actually showing me the best human-readable diff, because two lines after editing became one line, but it's not obvious for scripts. So,

- Is this behaviour intended? (git 1.9.1)
- If it is, is there a way to get some additional output about these merges (and, if there are, unmerges)? It not, how to find them some other way?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what `--word-diff` is supposed to do. Git splits files to words (with " " as delimiter) and shows minimal chunks. You can see that your lines are always splitted on spaces.

Try using `--word-diff-regex=<regex>` with endline chars.

As for information about merges: [git blame](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) may be useful here.

Comment: You do mean to treat "[:space:]+\n" as a word? As I understand, \n are ignored as a word part.

Comment: I mean to treat "[:space:]+\n" as a word delimiter. So strings of your files will become "words" for git.

Comment: What for? I really need `word-diff` and to look up lines I am using standart (no `--word-diff`) mode.